# Is there a way to dynamically count the number of columns?

Tags: tables, expl3

I have the following,

```latex
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm, varwidth]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\tbl{mmm} {
  \begin{table}[hbtp]
    \begin{tabular}{ ||*{5}{c|}| } \hline
      #2
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{#1}\label{#3}
  \end{table}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\tbl{Symbols table.}{
  This & That & Who & What & Why \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
}{symb}
\end{document}
```

It works, but note that right now I have hard coded the number of columns inside the command, i. e., `{ ||*{5}{c|}| }`. Could that be somehow dynamically computed using `#2`? Maybe counting the ampersands plus one?

Comment: Computing it dynamically (e.g. using numberOfAmpersandsInFirstRow+1, if this is possible) will require that you *always* put all possible apersands in your first line, i.e. you don't leave some of them out nor use `\multicolumn`. This will probably not always be the case.

Comment: tables almost always look nicer without vertical rules. If you at least dropped the outer `||` you could simply use an upper limit such as `{ |*{10}{c|} }` (like amsmath `matrix`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give up with the double vertical rules, this is easy enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\tbl{mmm}{%
  \begin{table}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |*{100}{c|} } \hline
      #2
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{#1}\label{#3}
  \end{table}
}


\begin{document}

\tbl{Symbols table.}{
  This & That & Who & What & Why \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
}{symb}

\tbl{Symbols table.}{
  This & That & Who & What \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    \\ \hline
}{symb2}

\end{document}
```

Just specify a ridiculous amount of columns.

[image]

However, the syntax is wrong: the label is really difficult to see and should be an optional argument. Of course assuming this way of doing is better than typing in the whole `\begin{table}...\end{table}` (which I believe it's not).

If you are a fan of vertical rules and positively like double ones, you have to preprocess the table body in order to find the number of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\tbl{mom}
 {
  \begin{table}[hbtp]
  \centering
  \scribe_tbl:n { #3 }
  \caption{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2}{\label{#2}}
  \end{table}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__scribe_tbl_row_seq
\int_new:N \l__scribe_tbl_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scribe_tbl:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_put_right:NV \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
  \int_zero:N \l__scribe_tbl_cols_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__scribe_tbl_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__scribe_tbl_cols_int
     {
      \int_max:nn { \l__scribe_tbl_cols_int } { \seq_count:N \l__scribe_tbl_row_seq }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{ ||*{\l__scribe_tbl_cols_int}{c|}| }
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l__scribe_tbl_body_seq { \\ \hline }
  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tbl{Symbols table.}[symb]{
  This & That & Who & What & Why \\
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\
}

\tbl{Symbols table.}[symb2]{
  This & That & Who & What \\
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    \\
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    
}

\end{document}
```

You see that you can also simplify the input, avoiding all `\hline` commands. But, of course, the output is typographically disputable.

[image]

*Tutti i gusti sono gusti*

Comment: Could another optional argument be somehow passed which is set to the default of `c` so if someone wanted to use `l` in the tabular they could?

Comment: @scribe It's *much* easier to type in the desired table preamble.

Comment: I am afraid I might not know what that means...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\tbl{mmm}{%
  \begin{table}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ |*{20}{c|} } \hline
      #2
    \CodeAfter
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw ([xshift=2pt]1-|1) -- ([xshift=2pt]last-|1) ; 
      \draw ([xshift=-2pt]1-|last) -- ([xshift=-2pt]last-|last) ; 
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{#1}\label{#3}
  \end{table}
}


\begin{document}

\tbl{Symbols table.}{
  This & That & Who & What & Why \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    & 5   \\ \hline
}{symb}

\tbl{Symbols table.}{
  This & That & Who & What \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    \\ \hline
  1    & 2    & 3   & 4    \\ \hline
}{symb2}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]